Put object/file to S3 (parquet or CSV)
I'm struggling to put parquet file into S3 using AWS or AWSS3, if someone could provide working example (I can connect to S3 and get files). The only one which doesn't throw any error is below but puts only file body (file of 20B but when I try to open that file from S3 I'm getting "ERROR: ArgumentError: invalid parquet: final bytes are "quet", expect "PAR1"):
p = S3Path("s3://bucket/folder/my_local_file.parquet")  
write(p, "my_local_file.parquet")


Sorry, but your question doesn't have much detail. What do you mean by "puts only file body (nothing inside)"? Can you possibly edit your question to show us what you put in S3Path()? (Feel free to change the bucket name to something fake.)

sure, just added more details

The code is putting the text "my_local_file.parquet" in the S3 object. It is not a Parquet file, it is simply a text file.

how to put a file then?

This might help: Unable to Create Object with Content in AWS S3 Bucket : r/Julia

I have a local file on disk my_local_file.parquet and want to copy/put that file on S3.  Thank you for a link, upload_file_to_s3(bucket_name, template_file) solved the issue! Please provide an answer to accept it

It appears that you want to upload a file from the local disk to Amazon S3 using Julia.
From Unable to Create Object with Content in AWS S3 Bucket : r/Julia:
using AWS: @service
@service S3

function upload_file_to_s3(bucket_name, file_path)
    file_name = basename(file_path)
    open(file_path, "r") do file
        S3.put_object(bucket_name, file_name, Dict("Body" => read(file, String)))
    end
    println("File $file_name uploaded to $bucket_name.")
end

template_file="./README.md"
bucket_name="my-unique-bucket-name"
upload_file_to_s3(bucket_name, template_file)

